# How to call a HTML code from database using id of it

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm having table named as`blocks`[image]

I use this query in controller and code in view to display this template..

**Controller**

```
$blocks = $this->model->getData("SELECT * FROM `blocks`");
```

**View**

```
@foreach($blocks as $block)
   <?php $str = $block->template; 
      echo $str. "\n";
   ?>
@endforeach
```

Actually it retrieve all the contents from the table and show all the templates in view

But,If I need to call only that template of `briefcase` **identifier**.I just want to call the identifier name.

This may possible using query.But I didn't need it.

Since my table having more then 20 data like this, so by using query is not good thing I think so,

Is there any other ways to show that `template` if the `identifier_name` was called..

Someone help me..Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You should select the id you need

```
$blocks = $this->model->getData("SELECT * FROM `blocks` where identifier = 'briefcase'");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible using query only.
As you have written there are like 20 records with identifier briefcase.
In my understanding you want to use only first briefcase identifier

```
$blocks = $this->model->getData("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM `blocks` WHERE identifier='briefcase'");
```

this will bring only one template

Comment: What my need is When the `identifier name` is called in the view It should show the respective `template` in that place